# how to show string value instead of number in input field using angular

Tags: html, typescript

I have one input field  called status id which is showing now number in UI.
It displaying 3 records as 1 ,2 ,3.
In my typescript i declared these number with field variables like..

```js
statusId: number;
STATUS_INITIAL: number = 1;
STATUS_MODIFIED: number = 2;
STATUS_FROZEN: number = 3;
STATUS_DISCARD: number = 4;
```

```html
 <div class="form-group m-form__group row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <label for="colFormLabelSm" class=" col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Status Id</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7">
        <input type="text" id="statusId" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="statusId"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
    </div>
```

Now I want to show these variable names like STATUS_FROZEN instead of numbers.
Like 3 in the UI .

Can any one explain?

Comment: you mean you want to display the names of the variables to user rather than the value of the variable? Simply create an object, make the variable names the properties and the numbers the values of the corresponding property.

Comment: i created a textObject.but where i have to give the object ? Can i use it as statusId.textObject

Comment: i meant create a javascript object using `{}`

Comment: textObject: { [key: number]: string } =
  {
        1: 'STATUS_INITIAL',
        2: 'STATUS_MODIFIED',
 3: 'STATUS_FROZEN',
 4: 'STATUS_DISCARD'
  };

Comment: yeah that works or the opposite would work too. I'd say make the string the property  name rather than the number, but whatever floats your boat

Answer (score 0):

you can use key-value pair for this problem. Key-value pair is like that, variable/object "A", have key "initial-value" and have value "0". Now you can call key or value by variable/object_name.key or variable/object_name.value respectively. For more information visit this link, hope it will help you :  https://www.talkingdotnet.com/angular-6-1-introduces-new-keyvalue-pipe/

Answer (score 0):

There are many different ways to achieve this.
You can create an object with Keys and Values:

```html
<div class="form-group m-form__group row" >
  <div class="col-lg-4">
    <label for="colFormLabelSm" class=" col-form-label col-form-label-sm">Status Id</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-7">
    <input type="text" id="statusId" class="form-control form-control-sm" [(ngModel)]="statusId['3']"  [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
  </div>
</div>
  
  <script type = "text/typescript">
        statusId = {
    1: 'STATUS_INITIAL',
    2: 'STATUS_MODIFIED',
    3: 'STATUS_FROZEN',
    4: 'STATUS_DISCARD'}
  ;
    </script>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: TQ.. but i am using previous and next buttons.every time i have to show one record either status id 1 or 2 or 3

Comment: @RajanBosh , You can remove *ngFor to ignore the iteration. Updated the code snippet. Let me know if that doesnt work.